# Microwave not working, sparks and discharges near magnetron

Tags: kitchens, microwave-oven

I have a microwave oven - standard cheap LG unit. It's no longer working (it made electrical sparking sounds), so I opened it up to see if it's possible with a DIY repair.

First thing I did was of course to discharge the capacitor for safety reasons.

I cannot see anything obvious here, but I am not experienced in microwave repair at all.

I'm including a video (the most interesting) and a photo.

I have tested the magnetron using the continuity check on a multimeter. It seems to be working. I've checked the big diode and the thermal fuse. Is there anything else I can check?

YouTube Link: [Showing how some electric sparking happens near the magnetron](https://youtu.be/uFqlte7LZv8)

[image: Shows the innards of the microwave]

Extra link: [A couple more photos if relevant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4frY.jpg)

Comment: Microwave magnetrons are [dangerous](http://www.microtechfactoryservice.com/safety.html) things. I'd expect it is very unlikely that you can economically repair a cheap microwave oven that has no obvious simple fix and where there appears to be a sustained high-voltage (~5000V) high current arc ocurring. A replacement might cost $70 - I wouldn't risk my life for $70.

Comment: Yes, fixing it may even cost more than a new cheap microwave oven. If I end up throwing it away, is there perhaps some interesting parts I should salvage for fun projects?

Comment: Yeah, I would not suggest repairing a microwave as a DIY project. The risks are too high and new microwaves are cheap.

Comment: Ditto.  Nothing this inexpensive is worth risking your life (or someone else's) over.  I admire your precautions such as discharging the cap.  But this sounds like a good time to just pull out the transformer and build a Jacob's Ladder with coat hanger elements to impress the kids.  Hint:  If you do, put it inside a transparent PVC pipe so nobody can touch it.  You can take the magnetron apart to salvage the magnets, but do not ever do anything with the radiating element - the insulation around it is nasty material, and one breath of the dust from cutting it can be much worse than asbestos.

Comment: Yes, for instance the transformers are great high voltage sources. In third world countries they use them to step up electricity for lomg distance transmission.

Comment: I like the idea about the Jacob's ladder with coat hanger elements. Might just try that.  But thanks guys - I think it's pretty clear that I'm not going to try to fix this. I'll buy a new one, and then scavenge some of the parts from the old microwave.

Comment: @Harper are you saying they use transformers out of microwave ovens in third world countries to step up electricity for long distance?

Comment: People use the transformers to make spot welders (they replace one of the windings).  You can find instructions on Google.  If you don't need a spot welder, a DIYer might be interested in the transformer.

Comment: To transmit energy with a transformer like this you would have one on each end of the transmission line.  One to boost the voltage and one to bring it back down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion - it's probably wise not to try to fix this.  As suggested by comments, it's just going to be too dangerous and not economically feasible. I will scavenge the parts from the old microwave and buy a new one to replace it.